# XML traversal by path in c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML like this I want to get Return/ReturnHeader not EliminationsConsolidatedReturn/ReturnHeader. I want to traverse the XML by a path like Return/ReturnHeader. I got this function in c#. The issue is when I set the path Return/ReturnHeader is also getting the ReturnHeader of all inside EliminationsConsolidatedReturn,ParentReturn and SubsidiaryReturn. Please help me fix this.

c#

```
    private List<XElement> GetNode(XNamespace nameSpace, string path)
    {
        var names = path.Split("\\".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);


        var element = new List<XElement>() { XDocument.Descendants(NameSpace + names[0]).FirstOrDefault() };
        
        for (int i = 1; i < names.Length; i++)
        {
            var name = names[i];
            element = element.Descendants(XName.Get(name, nameSpace.ToString())).ToList();
        }
        return element;
    }
```

XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Return returnVersion="2014v4.0" xmlns="http://www.irs.gov/efile" xmlns:efile="http://www.irs.gov/efile" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <ReturnHeader binaryAttachmentCnt="45" subsidiaryReturnCount="18">
      </ReturnHeader>
     <EliminationsConsolidatedReturn>
      <ReturnHeader>
      </ReturnHeader>
     </EliminationsConsolidatedReturn>
    <ParentReturn>
      <ReturnHeader>

      </ReturnHeader>
      
    </ParentReturn>
     <SubsidiaryReturn>
      <ReturnHeader>
       
      </ReturnHeader>
     </SubsidiaryReturn>
    </Return>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    private List<XElement> GetNode(XNamespace nameSpace, string path)
    {
        var names = path.Split("\\".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var element = new List<XElement>() { XDocument.Descendants(NameSpace + names[0]).FirstOrDefault() };
        for (int i = 1; i < names.Length; i++)
        {
            var name = names[i];
            element = element.Elements().Where(q => q.Name.LocalName == name).ToList();
        }
        return element;
    }
```